# Webpack Including JavaScript File via <script> Tag

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm using Webpack with Storybook and need to include a JavaScript library file in an HTML file via a `script` tag. Unfortunately, I get a 404 error indicating that the file was not found (the file's path is based on my local filesystem and is correct). How do I inform Webpack regarding where to look for my library or "static" files?

Answer (score 1):

Add files in entry object in webpack.config.js

```
entryPoint = {
    app: ['path/to/script', 'path/to/script2','./index.js'],
};
```

This will make sure that you have the library loaded when you have run index.js (entry point of project).

More on [Webpack entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, the exact files might be determined dynamically - meaning it would be ideal if I could specify beforehand, "include this directory and all of its subdirectories". Is this possible? Thanks again!